# github uses adds old asset files when creating new release

Tags: github, release

On my GitHub project at [https://github.com/bfristensky/BioLegato], I have a release 1.1.1, and want to create a new release 1.1.2 using "Draft a new release", which includes the current main branch.

Initially, when I created 1.1.2, the 1.1.2 release page would always show the asset files (ie. .zip and .tar.gz) from the previous version. The filenames were v1.1.2.zip v1.1.2.tar.gz, but the dates were from 1.1.1, more than a year ago. Downloading the 1.1.2 files verified that these were the old version, and not 1.1.2.
I deleted 1.1.2, and rebuilt the Java project, and pushed it to main, hoping to force github to create new asset files. Instead, now I got the from the initial build of 1.1.2. I checked to make sure that the revised files were seen in main. I have tried several cycles of deleting 1.1.2 and re-creating it. I even tried creating a 1.1.3, but now 1.1.3 has the asset files from 1.1.2. I don't want to have a release where the asset file have a different number from the release number.

It kind of seems like "Draft a new release" is adding the previous asset files to the new release, when the expected behavior should be to create new .zip and .tar.gz files each time.

Comment: SOLUTION: You have to delete the old tag as well as deleting the release. The old tag (eg. 1.1.2) will still point to previous files. 

What I didn't know was that tags contain metadata that point to whatever version of files you were referring to when the tag was created. A tag is much more than just a convenient character string.